# Can not get apache coredump file to find the origin of segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, apache2, apache2.4

I'm getting a segmentation fault for child process of apache.

To find out which PHP module is responsible for this I entered `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp` statement in my apache2.conf file.

I changed limits to (`ulimit -a`):

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31254
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31254
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

My Apache 2.4 is the latest `2.4.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` from Ondrej's https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2 repository, and PHP5.6 is also from Ondrej's repository https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/

In spite of the above preparations I still unable to get apache dump file and corresponding records in error.log like `possible coredump ...`.

This segment fault happens only when I begin debugging my site in PHPStorm.
Also, it happens only when I debug some PHP stuff encoded with IonCube. I can debug any unencoded code.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Due to the types of code protection used, trying to "debug" protected code is going to fail. If the debugger doesn't do good validation, it may well crash due to reasons such as following invalid pointers that mean something to ionCube but that will lead you astray if you blindly follow them. Best is to work with the original source code.

Comment: @Nick, thank you. I came to the same conclusion. I found code looping due to module encryption. Most likely apache will not create coredump file in such circumstances.